# Open Excel files as per list and update

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below table with file path and the information I need to update
[image]

And I am using VBA

```
   Sub ReplcaseDate()
   
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\INawab\Downloads\DMM FBO\Operation\Standerd SPA Roster Operation 2022.xlsm"
   Sheets("JAN").Unprotect
   Range("F3:F5").Value = "1/1/2022"
   Sheets("JAN").Protect

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I want to run the VBA as per the list until the list is finished.

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your sub to replace the date as follows

```
Sub ReplaceDate(wkbName As String)
   
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wkbName)

    With wkb
        .Sheets("JAN").Unprotect
        .Sheets("JAN").Range("F3:F5").Value = ("1/1/2022")
        .Seets("JAN").Protect
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

The sub expects now a filename which it will open and do your modifications to the sheet.

The following sub will loop over all entries in a given range and call the above sub for each single file. As you did not really specify how the input range looks like I just assumed the values are in a given range.

```
Sub runForAll()

    Dim rg As Range, sngCell As Range
    Set rg = Range("A2:A20")        ' Adjust accordingly

    ' Loop over the filenames
    For Each sngCell In rg
        ReplaceDate sngCell.Value
    Next sngCell
End Sub
```

**Update** I adjusted your sub to replace the date as follows

```
Sub ReplaceDate(wkbName As String, dt as string)
   
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wkbName)

    With wkb
        .Sheets("JAN").Unprotect
        .Sheets("JAN").Range("F3:F5").Value = dt
        .Sheets("JAN").Protect
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

The sub expects now a filename which it will open and do your modifications to the sheet where the variable dt will be used to replace the value in `Range("F3:F5")`.

The following sub will loop over all entries in a given range and call the above sub for each single file. As you did not really specify how the input range looks like I just assumed the values are in a given range.

```
Sub runForAll()

    Dim rg As Range, sngCell As Range
    Set rg = Range("A2:B20")        ' Adjust accordingly

    ' Loop over the filenames
    For Each sngCell In rg
        ' sngCell.cells(1,1) contains the file name
        ' sngCell.cells(1,2) contains the new date 
        ReplaceDate sngCell.cells(1,1).Value,sngCell.cells(1,2).Value
    Next sngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Storax,

Thanks for the replay since I am still new just to confirm; the Value (Date) will be adjusted for each file as per the date in front of it at the table?

Comment: You did not mention in your post that you would like to use the value in the column _date_ to update the single files. The files will be updated with  `("1/1/2022")`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: it Gave error 424 and pointed to
.Sheets("JAN").Unprotect.Range("F3:F5").Value = dt

Comment: Sorry, copy & paste mistake